# Как допилить проверку email нормально

Tags: php, email, if

Здравствуйте,есть такой код:

```html
                          
                            <!-- Contact Form -->         
<form id="contact" method="POST" onsubmit="this.action=window.location.href+'#contact';this.submit()">

<p>Введіть своє ім'я:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"></p>
<p>Введіть свій email:<br>
<input type="text" name="email"></p>
<p>Введіть текст повідомлення:<br>
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="5" ></textarea>
</p>
<p>Введіть цифри: <br>
  <?php 
  $i=1;
  do
  {
  $num[$i] = mt_rand(0,9);
  echo "<img src='img/".$num[$i].".gif' border='0' align='bottom' vspace='5px'>";
  $i++;
  }
  while ($i<5);
  $captcha = $num[1].$num[2].$num[3].$num[4];
  ?>
<input name="captcha" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $captcha ;?>">
<input name="pr" style=" margin-bottom:11px" type="text" size="6" maxlength="4"></p>
<p><input type="submit" class="bt1" value="Відправити повідомлення"></p>


<?php
/* Проверяем существуют ли переменные, которые передала форма обратной связи. 
   Если не существуют, то мы их создаем.
   Если форма передала пустые значения мы их удаляем */
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name']; if ($name == '') {unset($name);}}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email']; if ($email == '') {unset($email);}}
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {$message = $_POST['message']; if ($message == '') {unset($message);}}
if (isset($_POST['pr'])){$pr = $_POST['pr']; if ($pr == '') {unset($pr);}}
if (isset($_POST['captcha'])){$captcha = $_POST['captcha'];}

 

/* Проверяем заполнены ли все поля */
if (isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($message) && isset($pr))
{

/* Убираем все лишние пробелы, а также преобразуем все теги HTML в символы*/
$name = htmlspecialchars(trim($name));
$email = htmlspecialchars(trim($email));
$message = htmlspecialchars(trim($message));

/* Проверяем правильность ввода email-адреса */
if(!preg_match("/[0-9a-z_]+@[0-9a-z_^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/i", $email))
{
echo "<p>Невірний формат e-mail адреси!</p>";
}

/* Проверяем правильность ввода капчи */
  if ($captcha == $pr)
  {
/* Формируем сообщение */
$address = "my@gmail.com";
$sub = "Повідомлення з site.ru";
$mes = "Автор: $name \nE-mail відправника: $email \nТекст листа: \n$message";

/* Отправка сообщения */
$verify = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email");
      if ($verify == 'true')
      {
       echo "Дякуємо! Ваше повідомлення відправлено";
      }
      else 
   {
   echo "Ваше повідомлення не відправлено!";
   }
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Ви не вірно ввели числа";
  }
}
else

  
?>
```

Но,его недостаток в том,что он отправляет сообщение даже если email указан без @ как это исправить ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.examples.validation.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. у Вас сейчас при даже неверном *email* скрипт благополучно работает дальше, вам надо изменить следующее:

**UPD:** Лучше использовать [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php).

```
/* Проверяем правильность ввода email-адреса */
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    // Тут либо завершайте скрипт, либо делайте else и туда суйте следующий код.
} else {
    // А тут надо остальное ...
}
```

**P.S. Не стоит использовать это регулярное выражение =)**

---

Результат:

```html
<!-- Contact Form -->
<form id="contact" method="POST" onsubmit="this.action=window.location.href+'#contact';this.submit()">

  <p>Введіть своє ім'я:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name"></p>
  <p>Введіть свій email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email"></p>
  <p>Введіть текст повідомлення:<br>
    <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>Введіть цифри: <br>
    <?php
$i = 1;
do {
    $num[$i] = mt_rand(0, 9);
    echo "<img src='img/" . $num[$i] . ".gif' border='0' align='bottom' vspace='5px'>";
    $i++;
} while ($i < 5);
$captcha = $num[1] . $num[2] . $num[3] . $num[4];
?>
      <input name="captcha" type="hidden" value="<?php
echo $captcha;
?>">
      <input name="pr" style=" margin-bottom:11px" type="text" size="6" maxlength="4"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" class="bt1" value="Відправити повідомлення"></p>


  <?php
/* Проверяем существуют ли переменные, которые передала форма обратной связи. 
Если не существуют, то мы их создаем.
Если форма передала пустые значения мы их удаляем */
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if ($name == '') {
        unset($name);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if ($email == '') {
        unset($email);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if ($message == '') {
        unset($message);
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['pr'])) {
    $pr = $_POST['pr'];
    if ($pr == '') {
        unset($pr);
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['captcha'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
}

/* Проверяем заполнены ли все поля */
if (isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($message) && isset($pr)) {
    
    /* Убираем все лишние пробелы, а также преобразуем все теги HTML в символы*/
    $name    = htmlspecialchars(trim($name));
    $email   = htmlspecialchars(trim($email));
    $message = htmlspecialchars(trim($message));
    
    /* Проверяем правильность ввода email-адреса */
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<p>Невірний формат e-mail адреси!</p>";
    } else {
// ADDED ELSE
      /* Проверяем правильность ввода капчи */
      if ($captcha == $pr) {
          /* Формируем сообщение */
          $address = "my@gmail.com";
          $sub     = "Повідомлення з site.ru";
          $mes     = "Автор: $name \nE-mail відправника: $email \nТекст листа: \n$message";
        
          /* Отправка сообщения */
          $verify = mail($address, $sub, $mes, "Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email");
          if ($verify == 'true') {
            echo "Дякуємо! Ваше повідомлення відправлено";
          } else {
              echo "Ваше повідомлення не відправлено!";
          }
       } else {
        echo "Ви не вірно ввели числа";
       }
    }
} 
    
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо,большое за помощь!С праздниками кстати!

Comment: @CruzeFan, спасибо, Вас тоже =)